# 'COPY TO' query in cassandra for large data

Tags: cassandra, datastax, nosql

I have a huge data which I need to export that to a CSV. I'm planning to use COPY command.  Is there any way I can use the where clause in the same COPY query or I can specify the limit  range (Eg:  copy first 1000 rows and then the next 1000).

Comment: You can set the paging size in CQLSH to use fetch sizes of N, which will automatically pull N rows, write them to file, and then pull the next N.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Brian's cassandra-unloader:

https://github.com/brianmhess/cassandra-loader

It's a full featured load / unload program for text files to and from Cassandra built using all the best practices.

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot.